# How can i make my particles spin/rotate?

Tags: animation, particles

The particles on the text/mesh for my app game are based on the large star pictured which has spinning animation data. I thought if i based the particles on this they would inherit the spinning animation. Any help i would appreciate as think this would be a nice touch on the game. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]